# How to update a 'total' textbox from the values in another textbox and radios with Jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

I'm struggling to get what i think should be a simple bit of jquery/javascript to work. I've got a textbox and 2 radio's like so that i want to automatically update the 'total' textbox when a user changes their values:

```
<tr>
  <td>Value:</td>
  <td>
    <input name="value" type="text" id="value" />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Postage:</td>
  <td>
    <input id="express" type="radio"    name="postageradio" value="PostageExpressRadio" />
    Express post ($3.50)

    <input id="registered" type="radio" name="postageradio" value="PostageRegisteredRadio" />
    Registered post ($5.00)
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Total:</td>
  <td colspan="2">
    <input name="total" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="total" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the bit of jquery i've come up with, which doesn't work very well in Chrome (it is slow to update), and doesn't work with the radios at all in IE. I'm sure there's a better way to do it, so any suggestions are welcomed.

```
function calctotal() {
  var value = $('#value').val();
  var amount = parseInt(value.replace(' ', '').replace('$', ''));
  if (isNaN(amount)) amount = 0;
  var post = 0;
  if ($('#express').is(':checked')) post = 3.5;
  if ($('#registered').is(':checked')) post = 5.0;
  $('#total').val('$' + (amount + post).toFixed(2));
}

// The timeout is used because otherwise the 'change' events get the previous value (???)
function calctotalsoon() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    calctotal();
  }, 100);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#value').keyup(function(event) {
    calctotalsoon();
  } );

  $('#express').change(function(event) {
    calctotalsoon();
  } );

  $('#registered').change(function(event) {
    calctotalsoon();
  } );
} );
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome and IE8 for me.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Found some more details about why the radios dont trigger in IE: http://norman.walsh.name/2009/03/24/jQueryIE

Comment: Yeah, looks like you might want to add a .click method to handle the IE "feature".

Comment: Wow, i thought jquery took care of all that cross-browser muck for you?

Comment: Plus, i want it to update as they type each character in the 'value' box, not wait until it loses focus. Which of keydown/up/press do i need?

Comment: Doesn't look like there *is* a cross-browser fix for this.  The .click way only forces a similar behavior, not the exact desired behavior.

Comment: Try my answer below.  I don't have IE6 to test on, but it *should* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I chose to streamline it, somebody else may have a better suggestion. Conceptually pretty much everything you did was good.

First of all, the radio button's "value" attribute now reflects the appropriate amount of postage that should be added.

```
<input id="express" type="radio"    name="postageradio" value="3.50" />
<input id="registered" type="radio" name="postageradio" value="5.00" />
```

Then I streamlined the javascript like so:

```
function calctotal() {
  var value = $('#value').val();
  var amount = parseFloat(value) || 0;
  var post = parseFloat($("input[name=postageradio]:checked").val()) || 0;

  $('#total').val('$' + (amount + post).toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#value').keyup(function(event) {
    calctotal();
  } );

  $('#express, #registered').bind('click change', function(event) {
    calctotal();
  } );
} );
```

I tested it in IE8, FF, and Chrome. You don't need to use the setTimeout. The postage value is now calculated based on the selected radio button's value instead of hardcoding the value. The radios are bound to both click and change for IE's sake

Fiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NzrBj/

Comment: I find that i need to catch the 'click' event in IE for the radios to work

Comment: I see. One thing I also noticed is that (and you can observe this in the fiddle too) jQuery 1.3.2 does not work properly (it has the problem you had in your original posting), so ensure you're using jQuery 1.4+ for best results :)

Comment: @Amleonard : can u provide a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736434/jquery-dynamic-addition-subtraction-multiplication-division-of-multiple-text-box

Answer (score 1):

To hack around the IE issues, you could add the handlers to your document.  This means you get more events than you want, but it shouldn't be tons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        calctotalsoon();
      } );

      $(document).click(function(event) {
        calctotalsoon();
      } );
} );
```